# After the update 8.7.14 to 8.8, the File module causes error when uploading a file

Tags: 8, files, updating

After updating Drupal 8.7.14 to 8.8, I have a problem with the File module: When I upload a file, I get the *This value cannot be zero* error message.

> [image: screenshot]

The file is however present in the site/default/files folder.
I have already tested changing the permissions, I have no PHP errors in the logs, I checked the /tmp folder, added a private folder, created a new content type with only the file field, but I still have this error.

I also tested thees patches.

- https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-08-13/3098718-core.system_update_8804.truncate_path_alias_tables-69.patch
- https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2862702-3.patch

Have you ever had this scenario?

Comment: Have you run the database update script after your update, and cleared the cache?

Comment: hi, yes i did all the commands...